# Java recursion with an odd request

Tags: java, recursion

I need to create a recursive method which takes int x as its only argument, and then prints "*" x number of times then prints "!" x times. Normally this would be easy, but we can't use any loops or any variables other than x.

What I have tried (**edit**):

```
public void xPrint(int x) {
    if (x == 0) return;
    System.out.print("*"); 
    xPrint(x-1);
    System.out.print("!"); 
    xPrint(x-1);
}
```

I want to make the recursion start over but I don't know how.

Edit 2: Problem solved. I didn't realize that lines after the recursive call line would still be executed, so I thought it would do the stars then stop and have to be restarted again or something to do the rest. I just had to take out the last line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Do you have anything else on your homework list?

Comment: The recursion should not stop until all conditions are met.

Comment: What you have tried is very close.  Why do you have the second `xPrint(x-1);` call?  Trying to make you think through your process instead of giving you the solution.

Comment: What do you mean by starting over the recursion?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void xPrint(int x) {
    if (x > 0) {
        System.out.print("*");
        xPrint(x-1);
        System.out.print("!");
    }
}
```

Here's how it works:

- If `x > 0`, then we print one `*` and call the recursion decrementing `x` by one unit
- If `x <= 0`, it means that we must stop and start returning
- Each time the recursion returns, an `!` is printed
- It keeps going like this until there aren't left any recursive calls to return from, at which point the method call ends

Notice that the code in the question is *almost* right. The only thing is that the last call to `xPrint(x-1);` is unnecessary - if you delete it, it will work!